# Is there any way to disable all parent view except clicked parent view in expandable listview Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

[image]

I want to create an expandable listview like the picture. When I click on parent 1, child 1 will show and parent 2, 3, 4, 5 ... will disable.

And then when I click on anywhere in disable area, parent 1 will collapseGroup() and expandable listview is enable.

Is there any way doing like that?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set setOnGroupExpandListener so if the group is epanded collapse the previous :

```
//Group Listener Close other groups on opening other one
        expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
            int previousItem = -1;
            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                if (groupPosition != previousItem){
                    expandableListView.collapseGroup(previousItem);
                    previousItem = groupPosition;
                }
                else{
                    expandableListView.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                    previousItem = -1;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why do you want to disable it? Do you want to use other categories(groups)? Disable how about removinge expandListener from listview?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put this code in your onCreate Method and it will work:

**Declaration part:**

```
int lastExpandedGroupPosition;
ExpandableListView lv_register_festival;
```

**In onCreate:**

```
lv_register_festival.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {


                if(groupPosition != lastExpandedGroupPosition){
                    lv_register_festival.collapseGroup(lastExpandedGroupPosition);
                }

                lastExpandedGroupPosition = groupPosition;
            }
        });
```